# If status is 0 then display restore button else delete button using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one button called as delete. If admin clicked on delete button then record will update in database and button will change to Restore and vice versa. Or if status is 0 then display restore button. I need to know where should I used if condition. I am able to update the records but when I refresh the page restore button become delete. Would ou help me in this? I want to make delete and restore process.

```
    <button type="submit" class="register-button" class="btn">Delete</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".register-button").click(function () 
{
        var thisButton = this;
        var id=1;

        $.ajax({
             type: "get",
            url: "process.php?function=b_delete&record_id=id",
            data: {
                record_id:id
            },
        }).
        success(function(){
            console.log("done");
            $(thisButton).html("Restore");

        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it change back to delete because it just rendered the page like you did on the first time open it. To make it retain the name's state, you would need PHP to help you. Solutions is, on initial rendering page, fetch the data from database and do some conditional logic on view page to show particular button or name. Another solution, you can store the current state into web `localStorage`, and for the initial page load just retrieve the item back inside web `localStorage` using javascript. With this, you can use some logic again to particular name on button.

One more thing, never change the button's name by just using click as it might lead into problems. You should change the button's name inside ajax `success` callback by using `data` that receeived from server side. In other words, at the server side, when the ajax request the `GET` method and doing some operation on database either insert/update, you need to send the result status of the db operation either success or failed. If success, then change the button's name as you like.

Comment: Thanks for replaying Mr.Ghazali, I updated my ajax code for button change. I am not understand the first paragraph. Can you help me with example?